# Update the local debian packages using ansible

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ansible

I am trying to come up with a deployment strategy in developer environments using Ansible.

I have a few builds (node.js) coming out every day usually in the form of debian packages.
Eg: my_product_1.0.0_33.deb is the corresponding debian for build#33.

I am trying to automate the deployment on existing as well as new environments using Ansible. So what is the preferred way of updating the build packages using Ansible?

Eg: my_product_1.0.0_44.deb is my new build with build id #44 which I want to install on top of the existing build.

I am going through the Ansible documentation and below mentioned is the way I think will work for now.

1. Check if any package of "my_product" is installed and if not installed, install the latest debian.
2. If yes, check if the right build id of my_product is installed
3. If yes, don't restart the service and leave as is
4. If no, uninstall the existing package, install the new build debian and restart the service.

Is this the preferred approach of updating the debian packages in an environment or is there a better way to do this in Ansible?

The debian packages I receive are not hosted in any repository and are local .deb files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the preferred approach of updating the debian packages in an
>   environment or is there a better way to do this in Ansible?

This is a reasonably common approach.  It could be simplified a bit by hosting your debs on an internal repo, but that's not necessary.

In general, you don't need to do things like "check if a package is installed and if not, install the latest version".  You just specify the package name to [the `apt` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html) and it handles the conditional logic for you.

For restarting the service if a new version has been deployed, look into [handlers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change).